# HELP! Frontend User Profile Edit Won't Update Email

Tags: php, wp-admin, front-end

I've read forum after forum and I feel like my code is perfect. But it still won't update the user email.

```
     /* Get user info. */
 global $current_user, $wp_roles;
 //get_currentuserinfo(); //deprecated since 3.1

 /* Load the registration file. */
 //require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' ); //deprecated since 3.1
 $error = array();
 /* If profile was saved, update profile. */
 if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

     /* Update user password. */
     if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
         if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )
             wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );
         else
             $error[] = __('The passwords you entered do not match.  Your password was not updated.', 'profile');
     }

     /* Update user information. */
     if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) )
         wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_url' => esc_url( $_POST['url'] ) ) );
     if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ){
         if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )))
             $error[] = __('The Email you entered is not valid.  please try again.', 'profile');
         elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->id )
             $error[] = __('This email is already used by another user.  try a different one.', 'profile');
         else{
             wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
         }
     }

     if ( !empty( $_POST['first-name'] ) )
         update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['first-name'] ) );
     if ( !empty( $_POST['last-name'] ) )
         update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['last-name'] ) );
     if ( !empty( $_POST['description'] ) )
         update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'description', esc_attr( $_POST['description'] ) );

     /* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
   /*I am not Author of this Code- i dont know why but it worked for me after changing below line to if ( count($error) == 0 ){ */
     if ( count($error) == 0 ) {
         //action hook for plugins and extra fields saving
         do_action('edit_user_profile_update', $current_user->ID);
         wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
         exit;
     }
 }

 get_header();
 ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post(); ?>

      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">

            <?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                            <p class="warning">
                                    <?php _e('You must be logged in to edit your profile.', 'profile'); ?>
                            </p><!-- .warning -->
            <?php else : ?>
                    <?php if ( count($error) > 0 ) echo '<p class="error">' . implode("<br />", $error) . '</p>'; ?>
                    <form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <p class="form-username">
                                    <label for="first-name"><?php _e('First Name', 'profile'); ?></label>
                                    <input class="text-input" name="first-name" type="text" id="first-name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                            </p><!-- .form-username -->
                            <p class="form-username">
                                    <label for="last-name"><?php _e('Last Name', 'profile'); ?></label>
                                    <input class="text-input" name="last-name" type="text" id="last-name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'last_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                            </p><!-- .form-username -->
                            <p class="form-email">
                                    <label for="email"><?php _e('E-mail *', 'profile'); ?></label>
                                    <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_email', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                            </p><!-- .form-email -->
                            <p class="form-url">
                                    <label for="url"><?php _e('Website', 'profile'); ?></label>
                                    <input class="text-input" name="url" type="text" id="url" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                            </p><!-- .form-url -->
                            <p class="form-password">
                                    <label for="pass1"><?php _e('Password *', 'profile'); ?> </label>
                                    <input class="text-input" name="pass1" type="password" id="pass1" />
                            </p><!-- .form-password -->
                            <p class="form-password">
                                    <label for="pass2"><?php _e('Repeat Password *', 'profile'); ?></label>
                                    <input class="text-input" name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" />
                            </p><!-- .form-password -->
                            <p class="form-textarea">
                                    <label for="description"><?php _e('Biographical Information', 'profile') ?></label>
                                    <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="3" cols="50"><?php the_author_meta( 'description', $current_user->ID ); ?></textarea>
                            </p><!-- .form-textarea -->

                            <?php
                                    //action hook for plugin and extra fields
                                    do_action('edit_user_profile',$current_user);
                            ?>
                            <p class="form-submit">
                                    <?php echo $referer; ?>
                                    <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="submit button" value="<?php _e('Update', 'profile'); ?>" />
                                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user' ) ?>
                                    <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
                            </p><!-- .form-submit -->
                    </form><!-- #adduser -->
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <?php if ( get_edit_post_link() ) : ?>
            <footer class="entry-footer">
                <?php
                edit_post_link(
                    sprintf(
                        wp_kses(
                            /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                            __( 'Developer Mode <span class="screen-reader-text">%s</span>' ),
                            array(
                                'span' => array(
                                    'class' => array(),
                                ),
                            )
                        ),
                        get_the_title()
                    ),
                    '<span class="edit-link">',
                    '</span>'
                );
                ?>
            </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
        <?php endif; ?>
      </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

        <?php endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

If someone could please help me out, please. I can understand most code but I still consider myself a "beginner".

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok.

Maybe this line:

```
elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->id )
```

Should be

```
elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->ID )
```

---

Every developer should start with learning how to debug code.

Otherwise you're just trying stuff like a headless chicken ;-).

---

**WP Debugging**
In your `wp-config.php`, change:

```
define( "WP_DEBUG", false );
```

Into:

```
define( "WP_DEBUG", true );// just toggle this line to false to turn off
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    define( "WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY", false );
    define( "WP_DEBUG_LOG", true );
    @ini_set( "display_errors", 0 );
    define( "SCRIPT_DEBUG", true );
}
```

Then install a [debug log viewer](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-log-viewer/) plugin.

---

When you got the debug log up and running. Add `error_log('debug log is working');` directly to your functions.php and check if it's working.

Next, debug your code and check everything.

Example:

```
/* First check if the email is set correctly */
error_log('email: '.$_POST['email']);

/* Update user information. */
if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) )
   wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_url' => esc_url( $_POST['url'] ) ) );
if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ){
  if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )))
    $error[] = __('The Email you entered is not valid.  please try again.', 'profile');
  elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->id )
    $error[] = __('This email is already used by another user.  try a different one.', 'profile');
  else{
    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
  }
}

/* Check if there's an error */
error_log('error array: <pre>'.print_r($error,true).'</pre>');
```

Check everything untill you find the problem.

You can report back if you found something and you don't know how to fix it.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: OMG thank you so much for a freakin quick suggestion. I'll test it now and really appreciate it Bjorn!